How can I develop to purchase NFT in Solana and anchor
Help me please~~~
Could you send me a sample code or project?

I wouldn't recommend doing this with anchor unless you want to spend countless hours digging through Tensor's or Magic Eden's IDL files.
Tensor has an open-sourced TS SDK which you can use for V1 Metaplex NFT and Compressed NFTs
For example, you could make use of the buy NFT method from the swap SDK

Thank you for your help and kind attention.
But I wanna develop my Mint NFT selling and buying program with the anchor.
Thank you for your time.
